# XML::LibXML - detect if two Elements are the same?

Tags: perl, libxml2, xml-libxml

I'm working with [`XML::LibXML`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML) in Perl.

Say I have two `$element` references gotten by different (opaque) XPath queries.

(How) can I determine, if the two `$element` (Node) refs are the same element in the document tree?

Comparing `$el1 == $el2`doesn't always work as far as I could tell.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `==` doesn't ever work. It's a numeric comparison and there is, as far as `ack` says, no overloading of the operator in the library to check object equality. It might appear to work b/c strings are treated as `0` in perl in numeric context, eg: `perl -le 'print "OK" if "this" == "that"'` --> OK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the [`XML::LibXML::Node`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aNode) documentation:

---

> **isSameNode**
>
> ```
> $bool = $node->isSameNode( $other_node );
> ```
>
> returns `TRUE (1)` if the given nodes refer to the same node structure,
>   otherwise `FALSE (0)` is returned.